# Spring Boot AOP not working for AfterThrow

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

```
package test.aop;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.velocity.VelocityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Component
@Aspect
class LoggingMonitor {

    @AfterThrowing(
            pointcut = "execution(* test.aop..foo(..))",
            throwing = "error")
    public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable error) {
        System.out.println(joinPoint);
    }
}

@Service
class MyBean {
    void foo() {
        throw new RuntimeException("run error");
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    @Autowired
    MyBean myBean;

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner() {
        return r -> {
            System.out.println("Run");
            myBean.foo();
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the code above not working, but when I changed my pointcut to "* org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner.run(..)", it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring AOP works on public methods only. Make your method public, or revert to AspectJ.

> Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, protected
>   methods are by definition not intercepted, neither for JDK proxies
>   (where this isn’t applicable) nor for CGLIB proxies (where this is
>   technically possible but not recommendable for AOP purposes). As a
>   consequence, any given pointcut will be matched against public methods
>   only! If your interception needs include protected/private methods or
>   even constructors, consider the use of Spring-driven native AspectJ
>   weaving instead of Spring’s proxy-based AOP framework. This
>   constitutes a different mode of AOP usage with different
>   characteristics, so be sure to make yourself familiar with weaving
>   first before making a decision.

[Source](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)